# Symfony, Doctrine and "Proxy Classes are always regenerating"

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine

I just learnt about the

```
php app/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings
```

command and when I execute it, the console answers back with: **"Proxy Classes are always regenerating"**.

I can't find too much information about this warning online, and I can't for the life of me figure out what does this message mean.

Does anyone know a solution for this warning?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It caused by option in `app/config/config.yml`

which looks like:

```
doctrine:    
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
```

All commands by default have debug mode enabled so `auto_generate_proxy_classes` is set to `true`.
to disable kernel.debug in commands you should use `--no-debug` option.

so at the end command should looks like that:

```
php app/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings --no-debug --env=prod
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are using Google properly? :)

Get a look [here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=38243). It seems it is due to a debug mode. Try with:

```
app/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings --no-debug
```